# Corrigé contre solution contre correction

Tags: usage, synonymes

Les mots suivants sont-ils équivalents ? Pouvez-vous les présenter dans des contextes d'emplois distincts ?

> La **solution**, le **corrigé**, la **correction** [d'un exercice, d'un partiel, d'un TD...].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La **solution**, c'est ce qu'il faut trouver quand on doit résoudre un problème. Il n'y a souvent qu'une solution possible. Ne fournir **que** la ou les solutions dans un examen n'est pas ce qui permettra d'obtenir une bonne note.

Un **corrigé**, c'est une réponse type qui donne un exemple de ce qui est attendu dans le cadre d'un exercice ou d'un examen. S'il s'agit d'un problème scientifique qui a une solution, le corrigé inclura une explication de la méthode utilisée pour l'atteindre. Il y a bien sûr plusieurs corrigés possibles, en fonction du style du rédacteur, du choix de la démarche, de la matière, etc. Un corrigé est normalement rédigé *from scratch*, souvent par un enseignant qui se met en situation d'élève.

Une **correction**, c'est l'action ou le résultat de l'action du correcteur, qui commente, souvent en rouge, un document ou devoir rendu pour en indiquer les erreurs, approximations ou tout contenu qu'il pense devoir être souligné.

Answer (score 1):

**I** Au substantif masculin « *corrigé* » est associé la notion de *modèle* ([réf.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/corrig%c3%a9/19448)) mais pas au substantif féminin « *solution* ».

**II** **livres**  Dans le domaine des devoirs, « *corrigé* » et « *solution* » sont synonymes ([réf.](https://www.synonymeur.com/synonyme/solution/)) dans certains contextes; ce sont les contextes où l'épreuve comprend un calcul, un raisonnement. On trouvera ces termes utilisés comme synonymes *dans les livres* : « corrigé des exercices » ou « solution des exercices ». On trouve aussi le terme « *réponse* » dans ce contexte ; on ne dira pas cependant « réponses des exercices » (incorrect) mais « réponses aux exercices » ou « réponses » tout court (quand il y en a plusieurs, autrement le mot est évidemment écrit sans s).

Lorsqu'il s'agit de travail dans un domaine qui ne fait appel qu'à la mémorisation et lorsqu'un modèle est chose possible (thèmes et versions de langues étrangères ou anciennes, géographie, histoire, biologie, etc.) on ne peut pas utiliser « *solution* » ou « *réponse* » et seulement « *corrigé* » est utilisé.

**III** **examens importants**  Dans *le domaine des examens importants* on n'utilise pas le mot « solution » (ni « réponse »). Le seul mot utilisé est « corrigé », même en mathématiques. Dans ce contexte « réponse » ne signifie pas « solution des problèmes » mais « travail écrit par ceux qui sont sujets à l'examen en réponse aux problèmes à résoudre ».

**IV** Dans l'enseignement, la *correction* est l'activité qui consiste à corriger les copies ou les exercices et problèmes, et qui ne signifie jamais « modèles de réponse ». On n'utilise donc pas ce mot pour « solution », « corrigé » ou « réponse ». On ne trouve pas de définition signifiant « *corrigé* » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/correction) ; il n'y en a pas non plus dans le [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/correction/19424).